# document.ready is called before the ajax Get success

Tags: jquery, ajax

i want the `document.ready` function should called after the my `ajax` gets success.

In `jsondatachart.js` script i used one ajax method, in which i get the data from excel sheet and stored in window.`ChartData` as below. All my data from excel gets stored in window.ChartData but this is happening after document.ready() function is called.

// "jsondatachart.js" script

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Data.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {window.chartData=data;}
     });
```

In `html` page i have referred that script `jsondatachart.js`, the script gets loaded and the debugger gets hit in $.ajax. But the success function gets fire only after the document.ready function is executed. so the `window.ChartData` used in the main page is showing undefined

I am facing this problem in `IE` browser, in `firefox` its working fine.

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.globalize.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jsondatachart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
<body>
   <div id="container"> </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        $(function () {
         // var data=window.ChartData; (showing window.ChartData is undefine)
          });
```

In simple, 
  I want the `$(function(){})` should called only after the success function in ajax is fired, so that i can make use of the `window.ChartData` in my `document.ready()` function.

Thanks in advance

Comment: the document ready status is not depending on ajax request... all operations that depends on the value returned by the ajax request has to be in the success handler

Comment: You should put or call the code that needs `window.ChartData` inside the success function. See [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) for more information about how to structure your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all , Please understand the different between the two things,

1. **document**.ready and **ajax**  are completely `independent`.They have used for different purpose.
2. **document.ready** function is called , when your `dom` is fully loaded.It does not have any connection with **ajax**.
3. **Ajax** is used to get the data from your `Server side`.

   If you need to do any thing with your `ajax success`, please do the following,

   ```
   $( document ).ready(function() {

       alert("DOM is ready");

   });

   function ajaxFunction(){

       $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: "Your URL",
           data : "param="+"paramValue",
           dataType: 'html',
           success: function(result) {
               doWhatEver();
           },
           error: function(e){
               //alert('Error in Processing');
           }

       });
   }


   function doWhatEver() {
         // Do your work Here.
   }
   ```

Hope it helps.